# Incorrect Revision History

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, suggested-edits

Please see the following:
https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7181198

I did not edit this question.

I have edited some recently but not this one.

If I were to review the edit I would reject it as well!

It isn't an area I know anything about and even the language changes are not something I would have done!

Could there be some kind of relational issue with the SO database??

Comment: A quick check of the [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28764535/revisions) shows that your suggestion here is very similar to the initial question. Probably you suggested a small formatting change to the original just as nograpes made their edit. Your suggestion should have been thrown out automatically by the system, though, with a warning about the conflict.

Comment: Actually in your link I can't see my name - where should I be looking?

Comment: You shouldn't see your name; your suggestion was rejected, so it's not in the revision history. You should, however, be seeing that the initial question was very close to your suggestion. You probably wrote the suggestion based off that initial revision, before the edit that did go through, but submitted it after that edit.

Comment: Thanks Billy. I love that this question was edited :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did perhaps not make that exact change, but you **did** submit an edit suggestion to that post.

What happened is that another user, nograpes, *changed the post* while you were still editing your version. You based yours of the old revision, but by the time you submitted your change the post was edited and now your suggested edit looks like you did more than that.

Your suggested edit was submitted at 12:01:53, while nograpes had [edited their question at 12:01:41](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28764535/revisions); those 12 seconds are very close together, making the scenario all the more likely.

More over, nograpes removed the very lines that your edit appears to add in; what happened is that your old revision *still had those lines*.

Note that your edit should really have made similar changes to what nograpes did; the salutation and thanks was not needed, nor should leave in ` backticks around a code block that has been indented.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! I still don't remember editing it but I guess I must have done. Age is a terrible thing...